# iOS Swift 2 how to convert NSDictionary into NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

How to convert an NSDictionary into a NSMutableDictionary in Swift?

I have a line of code regarding NSDictionary that no longer compiles in Swift 2.
Please show me how to modify this line of code to bring it into compatibility with Swift 2?

```
let nsDict = anotherNsDictionary["amember"] as? NSDictionary
let mutableNsDict = nsDict.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
```

Xcode 7.3 returns the following compile error:

```
Error: Ambiguous use of 'mutableCopy()'
```

*I understand that this should probably all be changed to use a Swift Dictionary instead of NSDictionary, but major modification of this code base is not an option at this time.*

Comment: Are you sure nsDict is a `NSDictionary`? Tried your code and it works fine.

Comment: Check the type of nsDict. Is is of type swift Dictionary ?

Comment: Show us where nsDict comes from, because if it really is any kind of a dictionary that code should be fine.

Comment: Thank you @Jelly, @Amit89, @alexcurylo, and @EricS for your help! I edited the original question and added the source for `nsDict`, which comes earlier in the real code: `let nsDict = anotherNsDictionary["amember"] as? NSDictionary`

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

```
    let nsDict = NSDictionary( object:"obj", forKey:"key" )
    let mutableNsDict = nsDict.mutableCopy() 
    print( mutableNsDict )
```